# How to use Array[String] in a function expecting String* in Scala

Tags: java, arrays, scala

I have a function in Scala that requires a String vararg, i.e. `String*`. How can I call that function if I have an `Array[String]`?

Comment: A word of notation: `String *` isn't a type, so "convert to `String *`" doesn't really make sense. The question here is how to call a varargs function with an `Array`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `: _*` for that

```
def f(strings: String*) {
  ...
}

f(Array("a", "b", "c"): _*)
```

Comment: no `: _*' annotation allowed here (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.